# Use variable for id in element declaration

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a superclass `DemoPage` and several subclasses `SDemoPage`, `EDemoPage`, etc. All of these pages have the same exact elements on them, with ids on the `SDemoPage` looking like `s-demo-test1` and the corresponding id on the `EDemoPage` looks like `e-demo-test1`. In my `DemoPage` class I have declared all of the elements, and I need a way to add the id based off of the subclass (calling class). This is what I have currently.

```
class DemoPage
  include PageObject

  @@subclass_ids = {"SDemoPage" => "s-demo-",
   "EDemoPage" => "e-demo-"}

  # class << self; attr_accessor :current_class_id; end

  def initialize(browser, something)
    initialize_elements
    super(browser, something)
  end

  .........

  def initialize_elements
    self.instance_eval do
      select_list(:facility, id: "#{@current_class_id}facility")
      text_field(:account, id: "#{@current_class_id}account")
      text_field(:service, id: "#{@current_class_id}service")
   end
  end
end
```

---

```
class SDemoPage < DemoPage
  include PageObject

  @current_class_id = "s-demo-"
end
```

but this does not work. I get the error, `undefined method 'select_list' for #<SDemoPage>...`

This was not my initial attempt. I first tried just setting an attr_accessor :current_page_id, and then initializing it, but that also didn't work. I then tried opening up the metaclass and setting the id there. Finally I did what I have here where I set a class instance variable on `SDemoPage` and I was finally able to get it to work with this code:

```
class DemoPage
  include PageObject

  def initialize(browser, something)
    super(browser, something)
  end

  .........

  SDemoPage.instance_eval do
    select_list(:facility, id: "#{@current_class_id}facility")
    text_field(:account, id: "#{@current_class_id}account")
    text_field(:service, id: "#{@current_class_id}service")
  end
end
```

but this does not allow me to set the id's based off of other calling classes.

I also left some code from some of my other attempts, like using a Hash lookup, but these still set the instance variable in the initialize method, after the page-object methods already realize that the variable/method @current_class_id doesn't exist

I'm unsure of where to go from here.

---

## Edit:

So I finally figured it out, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve this problem:

```
class DemoPage
  include PageObject
  include DataMagic

  def initialize(browser, visit)
    super(browser, visit)
    instantiate_elements self.class
  end

  def instantiate_elements klass
    klass.class_eval do
      select_list(:facility, id: "#{@class_id}facility")
      text_field(:account, id: "#{@class_id}account")
      text_field(:service, id: "#{@class_id}service")
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class SDemoPage < DemoPage
  include PageObject
  @class_id = "s-demo-"
end
```

Is there anything wrong with doing it this way? I do need to monkey patch the initialize method, as there is other stuff in it that I'm not showing here. So since I already need to do that, is there any reason not to essentially "create" the elements in the context of the `SDemoPage` instead of in the actual `DemoPage`? Or is Justin's answer completely and utterly the better way of doing things?

Edit 2:
I accepted Justin's answer, because in the rare case that I don't need to monkey patch the initialize method in PageObject, his answer results in less duplication and less code overall.

Comment: select_list is a method of which class?

Comment: the page-object module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to:

1. Define a class method for the DemoPage that calls the accessor methods
2. Call this method in the child pages, passing the id portion as a parameter

The DemoPage would be:

```
class DemoPage
    include PageObject

    def self.common_demo_elements(class_id)
        select_list(:facility, id: "#{class_id}facility")
        text_field(:account, id: "#{class_id}account")
        text_field(:service, id: "#{class_id}service")      
    end
end
```

While the child page would be:

```
class SDemoPage < DemoPage    
    common_demo_elements("s-demo-")
end
```

Comment: Hmm this is a good way. I actually figured it out a while ago, but I was testing to make sure that it worked. I will try your method and see if it's better. I'll post my method and could you let me know if there is any reason for me to not do it that way?

Comment: Actually I like your answer. In the case that I don't actually need to monkey patch the initialize method, your answer is the better one. Thanks for the help, I knew you would be the one to respond and help me out ;)

Comment: I do not see any obvious reasons why your approach would not work. Though I was wondering if we are making it more complicated than it has to be. Why not just use regexs for the ids - for example `select_list(:facility, id: /facility/)`?

Comment: Ah, because we are using GWT, and one side effect of GWT is that the entire html is loaded into the page. So even if a certain "module" is not visible and never will be, the html is still there. Because of this the id's are still there and we have to use exact matches. Else watir-webdriver might find a non-visible id before coming across the visible one and then it errors out with a `ElementNotClickable` error or whatever it is.